# "INSERT has more target columns than expressions" in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, elixir

I'm creating a function and using it with elixir. I'm executing the function and parsed it a JSON payload below:

The payload contains key-value pairs for the table and the function should insert a record, later I want to refactor to first get the table by ID and then format the insert statement using the schema I get in the tabes table.

This is the function I'm executing:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_record(data json) returns text
    language plpgsql
    as
    $$
    declare
    table_id    uuid      := gen_random_uuid();
    id          uuid      := gen_random_uuid()::uuid;
    inserted_at timestamp := NOW()::timestamp(0);
    updated_at  timestamp := NOW()::timestamp(0);
    columns     text;
    values      text;
    j           jsonb;
    v           text;
    statement   text;
    n         integer := 0;
    length    integer := json_array_length(data -> 'schema');
    begin
    for j in (select json_array_elements(data -> 'schema')::jsonb) loop
        if n < length - 1 then
            columns := concat(columns, j ->> 'key', ',',' ');
            values := concat(values, j ->> 'value', ',',' ');
        else
            columns := concat(columns, j ->> 'key');
            values := concat(values, j ->> 'value');
        end if;
        n := n + 1;
    end loop;
    columns :=concat('id',',',' ','inserted_at',',', ' ', 'updated_at', ',', ' ', columns);
    values :=concat(id,',',' ',inserted_at,',', ' ', updated_at, ',', ' ', values);
    RAISE NOTICE 'cols: (%)', columns;
    RAISE NOTICE 'vals: (%)', values;
    statement := format('INSERT INTO %I (%s) VALUES (%L) RETURNING id;', data ->> 'name', columns, values);
    execute (statement);
    exception
    when others then
        return format('{"error": "%L"}', SQLERRM);
    end

    $$;
```

And this is the payload I'm sending:

```
{
    "action": "create",
    "body": {
        "id": "2ed27f13-62d1-48dc-bbd3-0a031fe2712e",
        "name": "test1",
        "parent": "base",
        "schema": [
            {
                "key": "hello",
                "value": "some"
            },
            {
                "key": "world",
                "value": "some"
            },
            {
                "key": "test",
                "value": "some"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is the error I'm recieving:

```
%Postgrex.Result{
   columns: ["create_record"],
   command: :select,
   connection_id: 1718,
   messages: [
     %{
       code: "00000",
       file: "pl_exec.c",
       line: "3859",
       message: "vals: (62d2364b-9add-4c85-b964-45d6b86d7db7, 2022-01-30 20:45:53, 2022-01-30 20:45:53, some, some, some)",
       routine: "exec_stmt_raise",
       severity: "NOTICE",
       unknown: "NOTICE",
       where: "PL/pgSQL function create_record(json) line 28 at RAISE"
     },
     %{
       code: "00000",
       file: "pl_exec.c",
       line: "3859",
       message: "cols: (id, inserted_at, updated_at, hello, world, test)",
       routine: "exec_stmt_raise",
       severity: "NOTICE",
       unknown: "NOTICE",
       where: "PL/pgSQL function create_record(json) line 27 at RAISE"
     }
   ],
   num_rows: 1,
   rows: [
     ["{\"error\": \"'INSERT has more target columns than expressions'\"}"]
   ]
 }}
```

What I'm confused about is that there seems to be exactly the same number of columns as values, however, I seem to this error `INSERT has more target columns than expressions`.

Comment: maybe it should quote the values? An example insert : `INSERT INTO TableX (Col1, Col2) VALUES (1, 'some')`

Comment: I would look at the Postgres log and see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: Its exactly that I fixed it with quote_literal(j ->> 'value')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as @lukStorms said above the values need to literal strings I addressed the issue with quote_literal(j ->> 'value') for the json values I pulled from the jsonb

Comment: Wonderful, Good job!